# How to iterate over an array passed by an Input Decorator

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-decorators

I generate in my parent component an array of objects and I pass it through an input decorator to the child Component(Chart Element).

I declare my array `chartValues` and I iterate over the main data Object and take the values that I will need in my chart by pushing them into my `chartValues` Array.

```
chartValues : Array<Object>=[];

this.chartValues.push({ name: data.countryName, y: data.areaInSqKm });
```

Later I passed this `chartValues` through the input decorator like this and I receive it in the Child Component but I am not able to iterate over it and I cant reach keys or entries.

```
<chart #values [filter]="filters.metric" [values]="chartValues"></chart>

@Input() values: Array<Object>;
```

I don't know if I'm declaring wrong the Array Type because when I create an Array and I pass it always the type of the element is Object

[[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: See example application here http://www.freakyjolly.com/example-app-share-data-between-angular-components-using-input-decorator/ pass array of item in template to iterate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on this [working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mPVq8b?p=preview).
You don't need `#values`.
Any of these should work:

```
@Input() values: Array<Object>=[];
@Input() values: Array<Object>;
@Input() values: Array<Object>=new Array();
```

Comment: Yes! Now I know that this declaration works but when I pass an Array through an Input Decorator I don't know why but I am not able to access to its values

Answer (score 0):

Just change it as

```
@Input()
 values: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is really important to understand, the inputs of a component are not evaluated yet in its constructor.
So you should init your "chartValues" in ngOnInit lifecycle

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
     ...
     this.chartValues.push({ name: data.countryName, y: data.areaInSqKm});      
}
```

Comment: He says "I generate in my parent component an array of objects and I pass it through an input decorator to the child Component"